# validating dropdownlist in gridview using javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a gridview with dropdownlist in asp.net(c#).i want to validate dropdownlist using jvascript.if i dont select anything from dropdownlist that time script shud display a message.i don know how to get the name or id of that dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

You can inject some C# within the Javascript section, like:

```
var mylist = document.getElementById('<%= MyDropDownList.ClientID %>');
```

Be careful, though.
If you get excited and start changing values in the dropdown list on the Javascript side, you will get a security exception when you try to submit the form; I forgot what it was called.

Comment: it is not working..coz m using dropdownlist inside of gridview...and while clicking on submit button it shud iterate through all the rows in gridview...